# Why does the iPad stop auto-rotating when I start overlaying View Controllers?

Tags: objective-c, ipad, uiinterfaceorientation

I have a fairly hefty project, where I am loading a few view controllers, one after the other. First, a splash screen, followed by a menu system, and when the user clicks on the menu it goes through to an article view controller.

Putting all these in with shouldAutorotate... set to YES for all rotations, this works fine. However, I have a menu bar I need to slide down over the top when a tap gesture has been recognised. I have one for the main menu, and one for the article view.

If I put one of these in, it still auto-rotates fine. However, as soon as I put the next one in, the auto-rotate stops working. I've tried putting the menu bars in the app delegate, as well as nesting them inside the menu/article view controllers. The Menu Bar view controller also has shouldAutorotate... set to YES. In fact, *every single* view controller in the project (all 7 of them) have it set to YES. And yet, when I add my second Menu bar controller, it stops auto-rotating. It doesn't even trigger the "shouldAutorotate" method to ask it.

The code is way too large to post here, but if you'd like to see anything in particular then just ask. I'm totally stumped! I'm about to pull the menu bars out of their view controller and code them up in each of the view controllers individually. This will be a hideous amount of code duplication, but I can't think of any other way round it!

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer appears to be... Don't put view controllers within other view controllers! One view controller = one screen, seems to be the rule. I have a lot to learn!

Comment: Naw that is not true mate. Think of tabBar and navigatoncorllers

Comment: @UrbanSeifert - true, but they appear to be special built-in cases. There is something about putting custom view controllers within other custom view controllers that breaks some functionality. One might have to implement some method and pass through some value, but there is nothing in the documentation about it. As a result, doing so I find breaks the autorotate functionality. And I've watched Stanford tutorials which say this is also bad practise.